# Strange Omission of "to be" in The Onion Headlines

Tags: tenses, headline-english, journalism

So I've noticed a pattern lately on the TheOnion.com of omitting 'is' from their headlines.  I get shortening headlines but I can't say this pattern is familiar to me.  It strikes me as obtuse and hard to read.

Here are some links of examples I could drum up.  There are many more:

[Report: It A Miracle Nothing Has Punctured Your Eye Yet](http://www.theonion.com/article/report-it-miracle-nothing-has-punctured-your-eye-y-57027) (9-25-2017)

[Hope Hicks Praying She Not Still in Same Shitty Job By Time She Hits 30](http://www.theonion.com/article/hope-hicks-praying-she-not-still-same-shitty-job-t-56945) (9-15-2017)

[Man Must Think It Enough to Wear Blackhawks Jersey at Cubs Game](http://www.theonion.com/article/man-must-think-it-enough-wear-blackhawks-jersey-cu-56913) (9-12-2017)

Are they just trolling?  Is this accepted journalistic style?  Is there a name for this?

Comment: The *Onion* is satirical.  One of the things they satirize is the stupid headlines used in, eg, grocery store checkout rags.

Comment: *The Onion* is a satire site. One of the things they satirize is journalistic style, including headlinese that would probably not appear in a real publication, but are instantly recognizable as such.

Comment: They're satirical but it's still well written and adheres to grammar conventions.  If anything the style and linguistic conventions of the site are standard.

Comment: These examples involve be-deletion (assuming the indicative in the third example) rather than to-be-deletion (amongst other things). It is best to refer to verbs using the base form, not the to-infinitive.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Ah, so *they're* responsible for the honey be colony collapse!!

Comment: @Hot Licks They'll be sorely missed on ELU: their spelling was legendary.

Answer (score 2):

It's standard practice to omit to be from headlines, but what is weird about the Onion is they put a kind of isolated subject in there. normal headlines might be:

*A miracle nothing has punctured your eye yet

*Hope Hicks prays not to be in same job...

*Man thinks wearing Blackhawks jersey to Cuba game acceptable

What that last one shows is that the ugly inclusion of a subject makes for a more flexible sentence structure. Unless there are some terribly written and infamous magazines in the US I think this flexibility rather than parodying bad headline style is the most likely cause.